# Create new column in pandas based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some dataset about genders of various individuals. Say, the dataset looks like this:

```
Male
Female
Male and Female
Male
Male
Female
Trans
Unknown
Male and Female
```

Some identify themselves as Male, some female and some identify themselves as both male and female.

Now, what I want to do is create a new column in Pandas which maps

```
Males to 1, 
Females to 2,
Others to 3
```

I wrote some code

```
def gender(x):
    if x.str.contains("Male")
        return 1
    elif x.str.contains("Female")
        return 2
    elif return 3

df["Gender Values"] = df["Gender"].apply(gender)
```

But I was getting errors that function doesn't contain any attribute contains. I tried removing str:

```
x.contains("Male")
```

and I was getting same error

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
def gender(x):
    if "Female" in x and "Male" in x:
        return 3
    elif "Male" in x:
        return 1
    elif "Female" in x:
        return 2
    else: return 4

df["Gender Values"] = df["Gender"].apply(gender)

print (df)
            Gender  Gender Values
0             Male              1
1           Female              2
2  Male and Female              3
3             Male              1
4             Male              1
5           Female              2
6            Trans              4
7          Unknown              4
8  Male and Female              3
```

Comment: Found this from Google and this is the best solution I could find! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a mapping function, and use that to map the values.

```
def map_identity(identity):
    if gender.lower() == 'male':
        return 1
    elif gender.lower() == 'female':
        return 2
    else: 
        return 3

df["B"] = df["A"].map(map_identity)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific requirement to use 1, 2, 3 to Males, Females and Others respectively in that order, you can try LabelEncoder from Scikit-Learn. It will randomly allocate a unique number to each unique category in that column.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(df["gender"])
```

For details, you can check [Label Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) documentation.

Hope this helps!