# Pandas add column with formula using value of other column

Tags: pandas

I have a existing df. I want to extend it with a column RSI.
RSI is calculated using a function rsi_func(close) which returns a number. I've tried the official [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) see coding 2) and 3) and [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564372/create-new-column-in-pandas-based-on-value-of-another-column), see coding 7) and many other examples, I can't get it to work.
I've tried, without the numbering of course:

```
    1)  df['RSI'] = rsi_func(df['close'])
    2)  df.assign(RSI=lambda x: rsi_func(close))
    3a) rsi = rsi_func(df['close'])
    3b) print(rsi)
    3c) df.assign(RSI=rsi)
    4)  df.assign(RSI=rsi_func(df['close']))
    5)  df.assign(RSI=lambda x: rsi_func(close))
    6)  df['RSI'] = df.apply(lambda x: rsi_func(x['close']))
    7)  df['RSI'] = df['close'].apply(rsi_func)
```

When I try 3a+b+c then a python list with RSI values is printed. But 3c doesn't append RSI to df. How can I create RSI with the return of rsi_func(close) and append it to df?

Comment: ['close'] is a column in df with numerical values. A print(df.describe()) return the min, max, avg, etc. values of ['close']

Comment: `df.assign()` doesn't change DF in place - it returns modified DF, so assign it back to df: `df = df.assign(...)`

Comment: Thank you, df is indeed extended with RSI but all rows contain the same values in ['RSI'].

Comment: `"rsi_func(close) which returns a number"` - that's clear if your function returns a scalar value, then you will have it in every row

Comment: I suspect that the return of rsi_func is a list and not a single value. When I modify rsI_func to close*2 then ['RSI'] holds the values of close*2. I suspect therefore that my problem is in de rsi_func.

Answer (score 2):

You can use map with the lambda expression

```
df['RSI'] = df['close'].map(lambda x: rsi_func(x))
```

Test using basic dataframe:

```
def rsi_func(close):
    return close /10
df['RSI'] = df['close'].map(lambda x: rsi_func(x))
df
Out[11]: 
    close    RSI
0  20.02  2.002
1  20.04  2.004
2  20.05  2.005
```

Comment: I get a IndexError: list assignment index out of range" as result.

Comment: check for n/a fields in close column, updated answer with a test